# Questions Regarding Transactions (or table lock?) in MySQL/PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a question that seems pretty basic but am having trouble finding the most efficient solution.

Suppose I have this table, table `KEYS`

```
KEYS
KEY_ID        VALUE        USED
1             123ASD       1
2             ASD234       0
3             123456       0
```

I want to have an API (Going call it get_key.php here) that will access the db for the last value with used=0, return the key in JSON format to be interpreted to the user via ajax, and then mark the key as used in the db.

I've seen thoughts about lock table, but my worry is that there is a script constantly generating and inserting keys into the DB while tons of users will be requesting keys.

What is the best way to achieve this while still being safe against duplicate entries being sent out, table locks causing long delays in web page delivery, and still being able to insert while retreiving?

If you are still confused, here is a basic example...

get_key.php

```
//not real file just pseudo
//(lock table?)
//SELECT VALUE, KEY_ID FROM `KEYS` WHERE USED = 0 LIMIT 1;
//$key = $response['VALUE']
//echo out key in json format
//$key_id = $response['KEY_ID']
//UPDATE `KEYS` SET USED = 0 WHERE KEY_ID = $key_id;
//(unlock table?)
```

insert_key.php

```
//$key = $_GET['value']
//(lock tables?)
//INSERT INTO `KEYS` (VALUE) VALUES ($key)
//(unlock tables?)
```

I know this setup in production setting would be extremely insecure, but trying to make as simple as possible so you can understand my question properly.

Thanks so much for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use InnoDB or any other engine which supports row-level locks. Then you only ever have to lock the one row in question that you're selecting/updating, e.g.

```
SELECT VALUE, KEY_ID
FROM `KEYS`
FOR UPDATE  // <--- add this row
WHERE USED = 0 LIMIT 1;

... do other stuff

UPDATE `KEYS`
SET USED = 1
WHERE KEY_ID = xxx;

COMMIT;
```

MySQL will lock the record it finds, and then only this particular DB connection will be able to modify that record until it's unlocked or the connection is closed.